# rsyncing the first 100 folders for performance testing

Tags: rsync, nfs

I am trying to measure the performance of the newly set up NFS drive between our servers so I am trying to sync 100 large files. I have 400 folders that each only contain one large files. How can I rsync them? The following command gives me an error:

```
[12:53:56] jalal@ayan:/SeaExp_1/400_folders$ time rsync -arv `ls | head -n 100`  /SeaExpNFS/100_folders --progress
rsync: -rw-rw-rw-: unknown option
rsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at main.c(1585) [client=3.1.2]

real    0m0.039s
user    0m0.011s
sys     0m0.012s
```

Two of the servers are Ubuntu 20.04 and the other one is Ubuntu 18.04. The NFS is managed by IT. Here, `/SeaExpNFS` is the NFS drive and `/SeaExp_1` is an external HDD.

Comment: There's a better tool: `bonnie++` See https://sourceforge.net/projects/bonnie/

Comment: @waltinator thank you for your suggestion, but at this point, I exactly want to rsync the first 100 folders from source folder to destination folder on the same machine. Do you know how to fix the error as in OP?

Comment: you normally do: `ls source | head -n 100 | rsync -avx --files-from=- source/ target`

Comment: @bac0n [21:38:37] jalal@ayan:/SeaExp_1/TCGA/testis$ `ls */*.svs  | head -n 100 | rsync -avx  --files-from=- */*.svs/ /SeaExpNFS/nfs_performance_test` 
this didn't work. Could you please tell me what I entered wrongly?

Comment: `$ ls */*.svs  | head -n 100 | rsync -avx  --files-from=- */*.svs/ /SeaExpNFS/nfs_performance_test
rsync: change_dir "/SeaExp_1/TCGA/testis//*/*.svs/" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync error: errors selecting input/output files, dirs (code 3) at flist.c(2122) [sender=3.1.2]`

Comment: Source argument only takes exacly one argument, in your case current directory `./`. The last slash added to the `source`  changes the behavior to avoid an additional directory level at the target.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$ find . -name "*.svs" | head -100 | rsync -avz --files-from=- /SeaExp_1/TCGA/testis   /SeaExpNFS/nfs_performance_test`